# Web Service para app Android

Tags: android, mysql, web-service, sqlite

Tenho uma dúvida. Supondo que tenho um web service salvando os dados em MySQL, esse service é responsável em alimentar uma app Android.
O usuário ao acessar a app será sincronizado os dados para o banco local do dispositivo. Caso o usuário faça alterações e não estiver sinal de rede os dados serão salvos localmente e assim que estiver online será sincronizado (enviado) para o web service. Como fazer isso? Uma vez que o banco aceito pelo dispositivo android é SQLite e o banco do web service estará em MySQL?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! A sua pergunta é ampla demais, tente ser mais especifico no que pergunta. Veja na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Olá. A sua dúvida não está muito clara. Como vc mesmo disse, a app Android não acessa diretamente o banco de dados, mas sim o serviço. As diferenças de formato de armazenamento são abstraídas pelo serviço. Por que você não edita a questão para adicionar informações sobre como está implementado esse serviço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo como isso lhe traria problema de incompatibilidade.  O aplicativo retiraria os dados do SQLite transformando em objetos (Java),  esses objetos seriam enviados para o web service que os receberia e salvaria no MySQL.

Falando bem resumidamente,  Java vai consultar no SQLite e transformar o que tem lá em objetos.  Esses objetos serão enviados ao web Service via requisição HTTP. O web service vai pegar esses objetos e guardar no MySQL.

Qualquer coisa,  exponha melhor onde você tem dificuldade de ver que dará certo que melhorarei assim a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Tássio, faz todo sentido para mim agora o que você falou.